# why shouldn't i save metadata when its a revision

Tags: plugins

I'm reading a book about WordPress and I'm new and confused.

Why does the author always not save data in the metadata box when its a revision. just in case its not clear, what i refer to by metadata box is the one added by `add_meta_box`.

```
//save meta box data 
function pp_save_meta_box($post_id,$post) {
    // if post is a revision skip saving our meta box data
    if($post->post_type == 'revision') { return; }

    // process form data if $_POST is set
    if(isset($_POST[’pp_sku’]) && $_POST[’pp_sku’] != ‘’) {
        // save the meta box data as post meta using the post ID as a unique prefix
        update_post_meta($post_id,’pp_sku’, esc_attr($_POST[’pp_sku’]));
        update_post_meta($post_id,’pp_price’, esc_attr($_POST[’pp_price’]));
        update_post_meta($post_id,’pp_weight’, esc_attr($_POST[’pp_weight’]));
        update_post_meta($post_id,’pp_color’, esc_attr($_POST[’pp_color’]));
        update_post_meta($post_id,’pp_inventory’,esc_attr($_POST[’pp_inventory’]));
    }
}
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You omitted how is this function called. I assume it is added to `save_post` action.

This action passes current post id as argument. In case of revision that would be revision id and not parent post id. <del>So, as I see it, there is no reason to save additional data for revision (creating duplicate set of it).</del>

**Update.**

Scratch that.

I looked through source code. Apparently `*_post_meta` functions will automatically change to parent post id if passed revision post id. So you might modify original post, thinking you are modifying revision.

Comment: yes its `save_post`, i see the point. are revisions like copies of the post data every time i save the post, so that it becomes something like a wiki? if so, i guess it stores a duplicate of the row, wont that bloat the database very fast?

Comment: @jiewmeng: [Revisions](http://codex.wordpress.org/Revision_Management) are indeed historical copies of your post. They are used to store previous versions if you edit an already saved post, but also for autosaves while you are editing.

Comment: Yes, revisions can bloat database. There is a constant that controls if (or how many) revisions should be stored per post (not counting one for auto-save) See http://codex.wordpress.org/Revision_Management

Answer (score 2):

When I look at my `postmeta` table, it appears no metadata is ever saved for post revisions. I don't think it has to be this way: I can think of some use cases where it would be useful for plugins to save additional metadata for revisions too. Take your example, probably from a webshop example: if I first create a product with a price of $20, then later reduce the price to $10, this will probably save the old text fields as a revision, but it will erase the old price fields. It could be useful to save a history of the prices too.

I assume the functions that deal with metadata don't fully support working with revisions of metadata, so we should not expect much support from plugins yet. But, if you create a plugin, keep in mind how saving (and retrieving) historical metadata could be useful.

Comment: Fields to be saved in revision are determined in `_wp_post_revision_fields()` and can be filtered, so additional data can be versioned. But it indeed seems to lack support for working with meta functions (see update above - they simply ignore revisions and bump up to original post).